# How to store and get req.user from JsonwebToken

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, mongoose

How to store and get req.user from JsonwebToken
I am developing a booking application using node the only thing left to do now is to get the user information who booked the product and display it in the admin portal

```
.then((user) => {
        const maxAge = 3 * 60 * 60;
        const token = jwt.sign(
          { id: user._id, username, role: user.role },
          jwtSecret,
          {
            expiresIn: maxAge, // 3hrs
          }
        );
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
        });
```

now i wanna access the user id from any router i have

Comment: Can you provide code example of what you have tried and please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Pass the token to your backend and deserialize it to get the data you need.

```
app.use("/your_route", async function (req, res, next)
{
    console.log( req.headers.cookie);
    var token = ""
    //HERE GET YOUR JWT and put it in variable token

    //jwtSecret is your secret jwt
    var tokenData = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret)
    console.log(tokenData);
}
```

Comment: .then((user) => {
        const maxAge = 3 * 60 * 60;
        const token = jwt.sign(
          { id: user._id, username, role: user.role },
          jwtSecret,
          {
            expiresIn: maxAge, // 3hrs
          }
        );
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
        });

i have done this in the back end

how to is access in specific routers

Comment: app.use("/your_route", async function (req, res, next) {console.log( req.headers.cookie) }

Comment: my encoded JWT is being logged

Comment: do this jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret) to get your data

Comment: If your the token starts with "Bearer " remove  "Bearer " token.replace("Bearer ", "")

Comment: could you code it looking at my code above

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.userId = (req,res,next)=> {
  const token=req.cookies.jwt;
  jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, (err, decodedToken) => {
    req.userId=  decodedToken.id;
  }) 
  next();
  }
```

and this is the file where I want the userid

```
router.get("/",userId, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.userId;
    console.log(id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```